# Вывод строки, содержащей порядок прямоугольников (jQuery drag and drop)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет... Такая задача: есть 4 блока DIV (прямоугольники), свободно перемещаемые. Они пронумерованы по порядку. И есть div (линия). Так вот при перемещении их на линию должна выводиться строка с порядком их расположения на линии (1, 2, 3, 4), ну или, например (2, 4, 3, 1). Спасибо не прошедшим мимо =)

Comment: Покажите, как именно сделаны блоки и линия, как они изначально стоят и т.п.

А вообще идея такова: при отпускании обьекта (`.stop()`) проверять и сравнивать позиции всех.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам нужен [JqueryUI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). Правда, там блоки не совсем свободно перемещаемые. А совсем свободные блоки - в [JqueryUI droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), но там уже надо самому придумывать проверку координат блоков.

Comment: Не совсем. Целью является вывод строки в виде "Эл1 Эл2 Эл3 Эл4".
Строка наполняется при добавлении блока на линию. То есть порядок может быть любой. При снятии блока с линии часть строки с названием блока должна пропасть. И если блоки поменять местами строка должна поменяться в соответствии с порядком их расположения относительно друг друга по горизонтали.

Comment: Ну так почитайте доки по ссылкам. Особое внимание уделите вкладкам Events и Methods. Вам надо просто написать функцию, которая бы выполнялась при окончании перетаскивания блока.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тоже при onDrop записывал значение offset.left блока и сравнивал с другими offset'ами, я думаю, нетрудно вычислить позицию.

Comment: а как определять какой именно блок в каком месте?

Comment: наверное вам будет полезно это http://jquery-docs.ru/css/offset/ почитать, а определить просто, узнаете текущий offset, находите ближайший offset (т.е. который несколько ближе к левой границе, это значит что он должен быть меньше, допустим на 1 единицу), и по номеру его индекса в массиве оффсетов находите индекс текущего элемента, т.е. он будет просто больше на 1. (Надеюсь не сильно вас запутал), кто знает, может есть варианты и полегче, если вы исп. ui, то рассмотрите возможности самого плагина.

Comment: возник вопрос параллельный. а как получить id того элемента, который сбрасывается(drop)? this.id, в drop:function(){} возвращает тот элемент на который было произведено сбрасывание, а мне нужен именно сбрасываемый при условии удачного сбрасывания

Comment: к перемещаемому элементу, если мне не изменяет память, можно добавить класс, по нему и узнать offset, а если изменяет, то посмотрите сами в firebug что твориться с элементом.